# Unmount NFS shared drive without stopping nfs-kernel-server

Tags: nfs, automounting, unmounting

I have a setup in which I have a Raspberry Pi B+ with Raspbian as file server, sharing a 5 disk usb rack. I don't whant the rack to be on all the time, so I turn it on when I'm going to use it and turn it off when it isn't needed anymore.

So far, I have been using samba to share the disks. Using samba, I can unmount the disks and turn off the rack without problems. When I turn the rack on again, the drives are automatically mounted and the samba shares are available again.

Due poor performance of the samba shares, I wanted to use NFS shares the same way. However, when I try to unmount the shared drives, I always get the "device is busy" error, so I need first to stop the nfs-kernel-server to be able to turn off the rack. That means that when I turn on the rack again, the shares will not be available until I manually restart the nfs-kernel-server again.

So, is there a way to reproduce the same behaviour that with samba (unmount drives and automatically share them when the rack is turned on)?

Alternatively, is there a way to automatically start the nfs-kernel-server when the drives are automounted?

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: Try running `exportfs -u /path/to/exported/directory`. You should be able to unmount the drive after that, without having to disable the NFS server.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful.I guess, however, that the shares will not be available again when the rack is turned on until I run `exports -ra`, right?

Comment: Yes, run `exportfs -a` to export them again.

Comment: Another approach that ought to work (I don't have a RPi) is to export a directory that is *not* a disk mount point, but which has mount points *under* it, with the `crossmnt` export option. For example, `/export/rack` is exported, and directories `/export/rack/drive1` etc are where the drives are mounted. The client will mount just `server:/export/rack` and ought to be able to see everything in that tree that is mounted. If you can't control the pathnames where the drives get automounted, you can use *bind* mounts to copy the mounts to be in `/export/rack/drive1` etc.

Comment: Thank you, that would definitely make the trick. However, I have tried doing as you suggest and the mount points are invisible to the client mounting the parent directory (exported with the crossmnt option). I will look into the issue and post another question if needed.